# combining tail with by in data.table

Tags: r, data.table

What's the best way to get the tail row of a data.table by a factor?

Say I have:

```
> dt <- data.table(category = c("A", "A", "B", "B", "B"), value = c(1,2,3,4,5))
> dt
   category value
1:        A     1
2:        A     2
3:        B     3
4:        B     4
5:        B     5
```

I want to get this, but I'm not sure the most efficient way to do it:

```
   category value
1:        A     2
2:        B     5
```

Comment: `dt[,lapply(.SD,tail,1),by=category]`

Comment: Also `dt[, value[.N], by = category]`

Comment: In case you have more columns that you want to return, i.e. not only the `value` column + any grouping column, you can use `dt[dt[, max(.I), by = category]$V1]` which will be quite efficient

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use `last`

```
 dt[,list(value=last(value)) , by = category]
 #     category value
 #1:        A     2
 #2:        B     5
```

If there are many columns

```
dt[, lapply(.SD, last), category]
```

---

Or another option if the data is ordered by 'category'

```
dt[!duplicated(category, fromLast=TRUE)]
#    category value
#1:        A     2
#2:        B     5
```

Or as @Frank mentioned

```
unique(dt, by="category", fromLast=TRUE)
```

Or we can use `last` directly on `.SD` (as @jangorecki mentioned in the comments)

```
dt[, last(.SD), category]
```

There is another `last` function from `dplyr`.  So, if both the packages are loaded, it is best to specify the `data.table::last` so that it won't get masked.

Comment: @Frank Thanks, didn't check that the `unique` also has `fromLast` argument.

Comment: what about `dt[, last(.SD), category]`? at first look should be valid too.