# How to pull specific field from a data.table based on multiple by-record criteria?

Tags: r, data.table

Using the [data.table](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/index.html) package for R, I would like to be able to pull a specific record based on multiple criteria. In reality, I am dealing with a table with millions or tens of millions of records, and I want to extract the penultimate entries of a given field for records which have terminating 0 entries in that field. I can identify which records are of interest, and I can identify the dates of 0 entry, so with some creative use of [lubridate](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lubridate/index.html) I can create a list of ID and "Date I should be looking for". How can I take this two-column, 100 row list and use it to return the specific 100 values I need from a table of 10 million records?

Here is a simple example of what I am trying to do.

Given the following data table `A`:

```
    Name Date Amount
 1:    A    1    100
 2:    A    2    100
 3:    A    3    100
 4:    A    4     99
 5:    A    5     98
 6:    A    6     97
 7:    A    7     96
 8:    A    8     95
 9:    A    9     94
10:    A   10     93
11:    A   11     92
12:    A   12      0
13:    B    2    200
14:    B    3    200
15:    B    4    190
16:    B    5    180
17:    B    6    170
18:    B    7    160
19:    B    8    150
20:    B    9      0
21:    C    2    100
22:    C    3     95
23:    C    4     90
24:    C    5     90
25:    C    6     85
26:    C    7     80
27:    C    8      0
```

What I would like to do is pull the last non-zero `Amount` for each record. What I can do is create a table `B`:

```
   Name Date
1:    A   11
2:    B    8
3:    C    7
```

What I want is the `Amount` in `A` for each `Name` & `Date` in `B`. The answer should be `c(92, 150, 80)`.

Another approach would be to extract the subset of all records such that the `Name` and `Date` field pairs are valid. I can probably concatenate the two and search that way, but in actuality, `Name` is a long alphanumeric string and `Date` is converted into POSIX, so that could get ugly.

Furthermore, I may be doing this the wrong way, if there is a simpler way to return the penultimate record by a specific field, that may be all I need, something that would function like: `A[Name %in% X, second-to-last record, by = Name]` where `X` is the list of records in which I am interested.

Thank you.

### Code

```
A <- structure(list(Name = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
"A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "C", 
"C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C"), Date = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 
7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 2L, 
3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L), Amount = c(100L, 100L, 100L, 99L, 98L, 
97L, 96L, 95L, 94L, 93L, 92L, 0L, 200L, 200L, 190L, 180L, 170L, 
160L, 150L, 0L, 100L, 95L, 90L, 90L, 85L, 80L, 0L)), .Names = c("Name", 
"Date", "Amount"), row.names = c(NA, -27L), class = c("data.table", 
"data.frame"))

B <- data.table(Name = c('A', 'B', 'C'), Date = c(11, 8, 7))
```

Comment: `A[Amount!=0, tail(.SD,1), Name]`

Comment: @ProcrastinatusMaximus And good old `unique(A[Amount!=0], by="Name", fromLast=TRUE)` ... I guess there is a dupe, since I've typed that at least three times in the last three weeks.

Comment: @ProcrastinatusMaximus Thank you, that works beautifully if I pre-extract the thousands of records which I need to look at from the millions of records in the table. If you write that up as an answer, I'll accept it, as it solves my problem 8-). However, would you know the answer to the more general question? Let's say the Amount value I wanted corresponded to various dates, not necessarily the penultimate? Thanks again!

Comment: Here's one dupe target (just for the last-row question not the OP's new generalization): http://stackoverflow.com/q/35704769/1191259

Comment: @Avraham If you want to extend your question, I think it would be fine to edit it, since no one's answered yet. Personally, I don't know what you mean by "corresponded to various dates" without more explanation.

Comment: @Frank I mean let's say I know I want the amounts corresponding to A 5, B 4, and C 6.

Comment: Oh ok. That's different. I would do `mytab = rbindlist(list(list(Name = "A", Date = 5), list("B", 4), list("C", 6)))` and then `A[mytab,on=names(mytab)]`

Comment: @Frank If it were three, that would be easy. I have about 8 million records to process and pull the 98 pairs of names and dates 8-) If it turns out I have to do that, I'll ask a new question, as the specific one I asked was answered here. Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no need to create the seperate `B` data.table. You can just filter out the zero values and then select the last observation. There are several ways of doing this:

```
# method 1:
A[Amount!=0, tail(.SD,1), by = Name]

# method 2:
A[!!Amount, .SD[.N], by = Name]

# method 3:
A[Amount!=0, lapply(.SD, last), by = Name]

# method 4:
A[Amount!=0][!duplicated(Name, fromLast = TRUE)]

# method 5 (as proposed by @Frank in the comments):
unique(A[Amount!=0], by = "Name", fromLast = TRUE)

# method 6:
A[A[Amount!=0, .I[.N], Name]$V1]
```

which all give:

```
   Name Date Amount
1:    A   11     92
2:    B    8    150
3:    C    7     80
```

Notes:

1. `A[Amount!=0, last(.SD), by = Name]` will not work and result in an error message.
2. Method 6 may seem overcomplicated, but especially on very large datasets the use of `.I` seems to be the fastest method. For benchmarks, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34753260/2204410).

---

With regard to your second question (as posed in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36139446/how-to-pull-specific-field-from-a-r-based-data-table-based-on-multiple-by-record#comment59918351_36139446)), you could use a join as follows to get the values of specific dates:

```
B <- data.table(Name = c('A', 'B', 'C'), Date = c(5, 4, 6))

A[B, on = c('Name','Date')]
# or as proposed by @Frank:
A[B, on = names(B)]
```

which gives you:

```
   Name Date Amount
1:    A    5     98
2:    B    4    190
3:    C    6     85
```

Comment: I'd give you an extra accepted if I could for answering the second question; thank you!